# Toggle Checkbox and radio button select using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, client-side

I have 2 radiobutton open and close and one checkbox Done .
If done is checked item should be closed ,if done is unchecked item should be open .similarly if item is closed done should be checked ,if open done should be unchecked .how to do it ?

```
<input type="radio" name="radStatus" id="rbtnOpen" runat="server" />Open
                            <input type="radio" name="radStatus" id="rbtnClosed" runat="server" />Closed
<input type="checkbox" name="chkReview" id="chkReviewed" runat="server" />Reviewed
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Either use radios _or_ a checkbox, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Try radStatus.Attributes.Add("checked", "checked");

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want to check/uncheck the "Reviewed" checkbox while you select "Open" or "Closed" radio buttons, you should add the following javascript code to your page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var rbtnOpen = document.getElementById("<%=rbtnOpen.ClientID%>");
    var rbtnClosed = document.getElementById("<%=rbtnClosed.ClientID%>");
    rbtnOpen.onclick = checkReview;
    rbtnClosed.onclick = checkReview;
    function checkReview()
    {
        document.getElementById("<%=chkReviewed.ClientID%>").checked = (rbtnClosed.checked);
    }

</script>
```

I've just tested this and it should work.